# Select first element that has certain property if there are any duplicates otherwise select first element

Tags: c#, linq

For example I have a list of objects, with those properties

```
{ ID: "1", STATUS: "INA" }
{ ID: "1", STATUS: "ACT" } 
{ ID: "2", STATUS: "INA" } 
{ ID: "2", STATUS: "BLO" }
```

And now I want to group them by ID, to reduce duplicates, but when the duplicates are found I want to check if any of the statuses is ACT, if it is ACT i want to select this record, but if there's no ACT status I want to select first occurrence of the duplicate.

In example above I would want to select

```
{ ID: "1", STATUS: "ACT" } //since it has ACT
{ ID: "2", STATUS: "INA" } //since it is first duplicate found
```

I know that the first step would be

```
var NoDup = from l in list.AsEnumerable()
                  group l by l.ID into c
```

But I don't know what to do next

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var q = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.STATUS == "ACT").First());
```

So first group-by the ID, then order the groups by the `bool` that is returned from the comparison `x.STATUS == "ACT"`. True is "higher" than false, that's why i used `OrderByDescending`. `First` ensures that i only get the first record of every duplicate-group. Since `OrderBy...` has a stable sort the original order is maintained even if there is no ACT-status.

---

Another similar approach which might be little bit more efficient is:

```
var q = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Select(g => g.Where(x => x.STATUS == "ACT").DefaultIfEmpty(g.First()).First());
```

This could be more efficient if the duplicae-groups are very large because the whole group doesn't need to be ordered by the `bool` if the first was already `STATUS == "ACT"`.

Comment: I like this approach :) How about performance if the list is really big? Will the ordering take significant amount of time if the list is more complex than ID,STATUS?

Comment: At first, I thought wouldn't First() break, then realized it won't in this case. Perfect answer @Tim

Comment: @Tim I agree with Piotr's point, suppose if there are 10000 of records per ID then wouldn't it get slow due to OrderByDescending?

Comment: @PiotrP: No, why you think it's not efficient? The `Status=="ACT"`-check is not very expensive. If it's a database driven LINQ provider performance depends on the indexes in your table. If it's LINQ-To-Objects you have to measure. There might be more efficient approaches but those are not as readable. If there is no performance issue i would not "optimize" the query.

Comment: @IpsitGaur: But i have added another aproach which is probably more efficient if the duplicate groups are very large. Readability is still fine

Comment: Yes, @TimSchmelter that looks great.

Comment: Just tested it with list of 160kk elements.
Without ordering it took 24 seconds, with ordering 38 seconds.
Not a big difference considering how big the list was

Comment: @IpsitGaur it's also 25ish seconds

Comment: @poitr Thanks for letting me know!!

Answer (score 3):

```
var NoDup = from l in list.AsEnumerable()
                  group l by l.ID into c
                  select c.FirstOrDefault(x => x.STATUS == "ACT") ?? 
                               c.FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from l in list
group l by l.ID into c
select c.FirstOrDefault(i => i.STATUS == "ACT") ?? c.First()
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done as follows.

```
List
  .GroupBy( iLine =>
            iLine.ID )
  .Select( iGroup =>
           iGroup .FirstOrDefault( jLine => jLine.Status == "ACK" ? ) ?? iGroup.First() );
```